# No way to send a text message

Tags: macos

I have updated to the new 10.0 and now my message screen only shows my messages and an edit option. How can I write a text to someone not in my contacts? I have no box on my message page for new text.

Answer (score 1):

Click the Compose button in the top-left of the window, then enter the recipient and message.

[image]